# How to detect the current account type in a Outlook Web Add-In

Tags: outlook, gmail, office-store

We have an Office Web add-in that is targeting the Appointment Items in Outlook (the calendar). It failed validation because, it was not possible to use it with gmail:

Functionality 
1120.3.3  Office Compatibililty 
The add-in did not pass compatibility tests for Gmail.

I was thinking about if i  can we detect what the current account type is from the: 
Office.context.mailbox.userProfile

However i am uncertain about what properties are available and if any can tell me if it is an Exahnge Account the user is running on

Please help?

br
Michael

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well Microsoft writes in their certification response, that we can ask questions here?

Comment: To my knowledge Microsoft doesn't own SO so they can write what ever they want on their website doesn't make it valid here.   SO is a programming site your question does not appear to be programming related.   If it is please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having include the error messages and we would be happy to help

Comment: True, i will make an edit

Comment: Welcome to stack [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  We cant tell you anything do your own research and give it a try and come back here if you have any issues. Include your code and any error messages you have.